# Windows Python Selenium chrome binary issue? No chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, typeerror, binaryfiles

So I'm fairly new to coding and I am supposed to be parsing Yelp reviews so I can analyze the data using Pandas. I have been trying to use selenium/beautifulsoup to automate the whole process, but I can't get past the chrome binary location errors in each version of the code I make. I feel like I've tried everything, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chromedriver_path = "C:\\Users\\5mxz2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver"

# Set the path to the Chrome binary
chrome_binary_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"  # Update this with the correct path to your Chrome binary

# Set the URL of the Yelp page you want to scrape
url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/gelati-celesti-virginia-beach-2"

# Set the options for Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode, comment this line if you want to see the browser window
chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_binary_path

# Create the ChromeDriver service
service = Service(chromedriver_path)

# Create the ChromeDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Load the Yelp page
driver.get(url)

# Extract the page source and pass it to BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Find all review elements on the page
reviews = soup.find_all("div", class_="review")

# Create empty lists to store the extracted data
review_texts = []
ratings = []
dates = []

# Iterate over each review element
for review in reviews:
    # Extract the review text
    review_text = review.find("p", class_="comment").get_text()
    review_texts.append(review_text.strip())

    # Extract the rating
    rating = review.find("div", class_="rating").get("aria-label")
    ratings.append(rating)

    # Extract the date
    date = review.find("span", class_="rating-qualifier").get_text()
    dates.append(date.strip())

# Create a DataFrame from the extracted data
data = {
    "Review Text": review_texts,
    "Rating": ratings,
    "Date": dates
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

# Get the current working directory
path = os.getcwd()

# Save the DataFrame as a CSV file
csv_path = os.path.join(path, "yelp_reviews.csv")
df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)

# Close the ChromeDriver instance
driver.quit()
```

That's what I have so far but I keep getting this error message

````
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6c92e956c704> in <cell line: 27>()
     25 
     26 # Create the ChromeDriver instance
---> 27 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
     28 
     29 # Load the Yelp page

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55f8912b24e3 <unknown>
#1 0x55f890fe1c76 <unknown>
#2 0x55f8910085e0 <unknown>
#3 0x55f891007029 <unknown>
#4 0x55f891045ccc <unknown>
#5 0x55f89104547f <unknown>
#6 0x55f89103cde3 <unknown>
#7 0x55f8910122dd <unknown>
#8 0x55f89101334e <unknown>
#9 0x55f8912723e4 <unknown>
#10 0x55f8912763d7 <unknown>
#11 0x55f891280b20 <unknown>
#12 0x55f891277023 <unknown>
#13 0x55f8912451aa <unknown>
#14 0x55f89129b6b8 <unknown>
#15 0x55f89129b847 <unknown>
#16 0x55f8912ab243 <unknown>
#17 0x7ff7aa929609 start_thread```
````

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of Google Chrome installed?  The path is different for 32-bit.

Comment: @DaveS I appreciate your help. I was able to get around the webdriver/chrome binary path steps by using my local machine, but now I seem to be running into a new problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76583472/22141623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following things:

1. Check if the specified file exists. Python:

```
import os
print(os.path.exists(chrome_binary_path)) # checks if the path exists.
# prints 'True' if the file exists, else it prints 'False'
```

or one-line:

```
print(__import__("os").path.exists(chrome_binary_path))
```

2. Check if you have permission to open that file.
   Press [Win] + [R] and paste the file path there.
   A message box with an error like "Permission denied" should appear if you have no permission to read the file.
3. Check if the hard drive is corrupted.
   https://www.avast.com/c-chkdsk-windows

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that no chrome binary was found at the location mentioned through *`chrome_binary_path`*:

```
chrome_binary_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"  # Update this with the correct path to your Chrome binary
```

Possibly, [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) was installed at a custom location.

---

### Solution

You need to pass the exact location of the chrome binary through the attribute *`binary_location`* as follows:

```
chrome_options.binary_location = "C:\\path\\to\\chrome.exe"
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140554/7429447)
- [Is Chrome installation needed or only chromedriver when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449076/7429447)

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was able to get around the webdriver/chrome binary path steps by using my local machine, but now I seem to be running into a new problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76583472/22141623

Comment: @Y0hno _I was able to get around the webdriver/chrome binary path steps by using my local machine_: How?

Comment: when I run the Python file using my control panel, the libraries I pre installed such as selenium automatically search for the correct webdrivers/chrome binary path