# No data found when webscraping with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm fairly new to coding and I am supposed to be parsing Yelp reviews so I can analyze the data using Pandas. I have been trying to use selenium/beautifulsoup to automate the whole process and I was able to get past the chrome/webdriver issues by running it on my local machine. It technically "works" now but no data is displayed in the output. I feel like I've tried everything,
can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I feel like it could be a html tag class issue with the actual URL in the code but I am not sure which ones to use and it's weird to me how there's only 47 reviews on this particular business page but there's 1384 rows in the created CSV file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chromedriver_path = "C:\\Users\\5mxz2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver"

# Set the path to the Chrome binary
chrome_binary_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"  # Update this with the correct path to your Chrome binary

# Set the URL of the Yelp page you want to scrape
url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/gelati-celesti-virginia-beach-2"

# Set the options for Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode, comment this line if you want to see the browser window
chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_binary_path

# Create the ChromeDriver service
service = Service(chromedriver_path)

# Create the ChromeDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Load the Yelp page
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the reviews to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY")))

# Extract the page source and pass it to BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Find all review elements on the page
reviews = soup.find_all("div", class_="border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY")

# Create empty lists to store the extracted data
review_texts = []
ratings = []
dates = []

# Iterate over each review element
for review in reviews:
    # Extract the review text
    review_text_element = review.find("div", class_="margin-b2__09f24__CEMjT.border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY")
    review_text = review_text_element.get_text() if review_text_element else ""
    review_texts.append(review_text.strip())

    # Extract the rating
    rating_element = review.find("div", class_="five-stars__09f24__mBKym.five-stars--regular__09f24__DgBNj.display--inline-block__09f24__fEDiJ.border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY")
    rating = rating_element.get("aria-label") if rating_element else ""
    ratings.append(rating)

    # Extract the date
    date_element = review.find("span", class_="css-chan6m")
    date = date_element.get_text() if date_element else ""
    dates.append(date.strip())

# Create a DataFrame from the extracted data
data = {
    "Review Text": review_texts,
    "Rating": ratings,
    "Date": dates
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

# Get the current working directory
path = os.getcwd()

# Save the DataFrame as a CSV file
csv_path = os.path.join(path, "yelp_reviews.csv")
df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)

# Close the ChromeDriver instance
driver.quit()
```

Here are some additional pictures and I just noticed that there was some information printed in the date column of the csv file, but they seemed randomly placed and not all of them are actually dates.

[image: mostly empty csv]

[image: some dates, some random numbers]

[image: local machine output]

Comment: use **id** or other specific attributes instead of class. For given url, you can use `reviews =  soup.select('#reviews > section > div:nth-of-type(2) > ul > li > div')`. This will give list of divs each containing 5 divs. Each 2th div contains rating & date and each 4th contains the comment. Finding the rating might be tricky. You can check the opacity of svg for that.

Comment: @DanielSabrel I am not sure if I understand what you're staying fully. Could you explain a little bit further?

Comment: I missed the aria-label for the ratings. My bad. What I was trying to tell is that there are 1672 matches for class="border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY" which is why you are getting that many rows. So, you might want to narrow it down first using id or label. And, you can also use [selenium driver to find elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) instead of BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten the code to do the same thing using `requests`, as selenium has unnecessary overhead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests

restaurant_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/gelati-celesti-virginia-beach-2'
headers = {
    'host': 'www.yelp.com'
}

restaurant_page = bs(requests.get(restaurant_url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
biz_id = restaurant_page.find('meta', {'name': 'yelp-biz-id'}).get('content')
review_count = int(restaurant_page.find('a', {'href': '#reviews'}).text.split(' ')[0]) 

data = []

for review_page in range(0, review_count, 10): # 10 reviews per page
    review_api_url = f'https://www.yelp.com/biz/{biz_id}/review_feed?rl=en&q=&sort_by=relevance_desc&start={review_page}'

    for review in requests.get(review_api_url, headers=headers).json()['reviews']:
        data.append({
            'Review Text': review['comment']['text'],
            'Rating': review['rating'],
            'Date': review['localizedDate']
        })
        print(data[-1])

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('Yelp Review.csv', index=None)
```

In this code, I am getting the business id (biz-id) and the total number of reviews from the restaurant page and using it in Yelp API to get all the reviews, saving it in a CSV at the end.

Sample output of the saved CSV is:
[image: CSV Output]

Comment: Thank you so much @Zero I didn't realize that what I was trying to do could be solved much easier  How would I go about including columns that include date the person who posted the review joined yelp, the number of reviews that they have posted, and the number of reviews they posted within a 1 day span of when the original collected review was posted (for example if the review was posted on 1/4/23, then I would want to know how many reviews they posted between 1/3/23 - 1/5/23). Is navigating to another page like this even possible?

Comment: @Y0hno, from the reviews, it's possible to fetch the user-id, which can be used to request and fetch about a user. Upon extracting the data, you can use `pandas` to filter/manipulate the data as you need.

Comment: And use proxies or VPN while extracting the data from *Yelp*, as they block the IPs if they request the website too much.

Comment: I attempted to fetch user IDs from the code that you helped me with and I couldn't get it to work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599996/web-scraping-data-using-user-id-retrieval-beautiful-soup).  And also, thank you for telling me about the VPN! I will be downloading one now.

Comment: as per this code, it'll be `review['user']['link']` inside the review loop.